# Moving webcam over from Ubuntu 12 to Ubuntu 14 - permission denied

Tags: 14.04, permissions, webcam

I am trying to move to ubuntu 14.04 from ubuntu 12.04, but I'm having some trouble with my webcam.

Specifically, whenever I try to access /dev/video0, I get a permission denied.

on Ubuntu 12.04, my permissions on that port are:

```
crw------- 1 root root     81,   0 Jul 17 17:51 video0
```

on Ubuntu 14.04, my permissions on that port are:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root video    81,   0 Jul 17 17:52 video0
```

Is the problem that this port is too open on ubuntu 14.04? Is there some default udev rule that is different between ubuntu 12 and 14?

Comment: How are you accessing `/dev/video0`? Meaning: what are you doing exactly and how is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

I added myself to the video group, and it worked. Not sure why the group ownership was different between versions of ubuntu.